# Not getting inside response.success [AngularJs $http.get..]

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a function `continueform()` on `ng-click` in a jsp file and have defined it inside the controller. But the program doesn't enter `angResponse.success` and instead goes under angResponse.error. Can someone please point out the issue here? Also, how do I ensure that `angResponse` receives JSON Object passed from validateForm jsp?

**JSP File:**

```
button ng-click=continueform()

**Inside Controller:**

angular.module.controller
.
.
$scope.continueform = function(){
    var angResponse = $http.get("/validateForm.jsp"); //relative path
    angResponse.success(function(data) {
    // do something
    });
    angResponse.error(function(data) {
    // do something
    });
}
```

**validateForm.jsp:**

```
JSONObject allContent = new JSONObject();
Map currAddressMap = new HashMap();
currAddressMap.put("current_add", "123");
currAddressMap.put("current_city", "xyz");
allContent.put("current_address", new JSONObject(currAddressMap));
```

Comment: What does the network tab say (in browser dev tools) when you call /validateForm.jsp?

Comment: If it's hitting the .error callback then your server is probably not returning a HTTP 200 code. Use fiddler or some other tool.

Comment: What you get if you do console.log(angResponse) after var angResponse = $http.get("/validateForm.jsp");

Comment: On calling /validateForm, this is what I get::::: {"current_address":{"current_city":"xyz","current_add":"123"}}.

Comment: console.log(angResponse) prints :::: [object Object]

Comment: UPDATE : The above code works on IE but fails for firefox and chrome :(

Comment: In Chrome, press F12 and check the Console tab. Are there any errors in there?